# solve two coupled nonlinear partial differential equations for 2 functions with space and time variables

Tags: differential-equations

```
eqns = {D[g[z, t], z] == (1/vg)(M*L -(r0^2/(Rd^2*f[z,t]^3))+M*(1+Rn*(r/r0)^2)*
 a^2/((1+X*g[z,t]/f[z,t]^2)^(3/2)))(D[g[z, t], t]-((2*g[z,t]/f[z,t])*D[f[z,t],t]))-
 ((4*g[z,t]*r0^2)/(Rd^2*f[z,t]^3))*D[f[z,t],t],
D[f[z, t], z, z] ==( 1/(Rd^2*f[z,t]^3))-((2*M*Rn)/r0^2)*f[z,t]-
 ((M*X)/(r0^2*f[z,t]^3))*(g[z,t]/((1+X*g[z,t]/f[z,t]^2)^(3/2)))}

bcs = {g[0,t]==Exp[-t^2],f[0,t]==1,f[1,t]==1,Derivative[1, 0][f][0, t] ==0};
ics = {g[z,0]==1,f[z,0]==1 };

sol = NDSolveValue[{eqns, bcs, ics}, {g, f}, {z, 0, 10^-6}, {t, 0, 3*10^-15},
Method -> {"IndexReduction"->  Automatic,
"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual",
"PDEDiscretization"->  {"MethodOfLines",
"SpatialDiscretization"->  {"TensorProductGrid",
"MinPoints"->  50, "MaxPoints"->  50}}}]
```

Comment: Welcome to SE! I formatted your code for you. May I suggest that you [take the Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and have a look at the other information available to help people use the site effectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works when you specify constants and rename `Xg` to `g` as `Xg` would introduce a new dependent.

```
M = 1; L = 1; vg = 1; Rd = 1; MX = 1; Rn = 1; r0 = 1;
eqns = {D[g[z, t], 
    z] == (1/vg) (M*L - (r0^2/(Rd^2*f[z, t]^3)) + 
       M*(1 + Rn*(r/r0)^2) a^2/((1 + g[z, t]/f[z, t]^2)^(3/2))) (D[
        g[z, t], 
        t] - ((2*g[z, t]/f[z, t])*D[f[z, t], t])) - ((4*g[z, t]*
         r0^2)/(Rd^2*f[z, t]^3))*D[f[z, t], t], 
  D[f[z, t], z, 
    z] == (1/(Rd^2*f[z, t]^3)) - ((2*M*Rn)/r0^2) f[z, 
      t] - ((MX)/(r0^2*f[z, t]^3)) (g[z, 
        t]/((1 + g[z, t]/f[z, t]^2)^(3/2)))} ; bcs = {g[0, t] == 
   Exp[-t^2], f[0, t] == 1, f[1, t] == 1, 
  Derivative[1, 0][f][0, t] == 0}; ics = {g[z, 0] == 1, f[z, 0] == 1};

sol = NDSolveValue[{eqns, bcs, ics}, {g, f}, {z, 0, 10^-6}, {t, 0, 
   3*10^-15}, 
  Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
    "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
    "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> 50, "MaxPoints" -> 50}}}]

None
```

Comment: M, L, vg, Rd, Rn, r0, X have some constant values. So in my equation, I am not introducing new variable, but it is X* g[z,t]; constant * g[z,t]. Do i introduce another function to inculcate that X value? How to  do that? I am able to understand what you said. Could you share me the results, because in my program, output showed is none.

Comment: @maninderpanesar, it would be good if you edit your post to contain the proper constants. What's the value of `X` for example?

Comment: M = 0.0495, l = 0.5736, Rn = 3.9434*10^-14, Rd = 0.00149844, r0= 5*10^-5, X = 4.85*10^-24, vg=2.859*10^8

Comment: M = 0.0495, l = 0.5736, Rn = 3.9434*10^-14, Rd = 0.00149844, r0= 5*10^-5, X = 4.85*10^-24, vg=2.859*10^8. I am trying to solve this equation but no results yet. Is there any other possibility by which i can solve it?

Comment: @maninderpanesar, you should edit your question to contain all information, like the definitions of the constants such that one can copy and past the question and try it out. Also, note that `i` in Mathematica mean `Sqrt[-1]`

Comment: I have created another program which contain all the constant values with slight modification in the equation. Please have a look.

Comment: c = 2.99792458*10^8; L = 10*10^(-6); t0 = 48*10^(-15); r0 = 5*L; a = 3; w1 = 2* Pi*c/L; wpw = 0.3; k = (w1/c) Sqrt[1 - (wpw)^2]; Rd = k*r0^2; E0 = 1 - ((wpw)^2); A = (1/(2*E0))*((wpw)^2);

Comment: eqns = {D[g[z, t], z] == 
   0.1 (A (1 - 1/(sqrt[1 + a^2/2]) + 
          a^2*(1 + g[z, t]/f[z, t]^2)^(-3/2)) - 
       1/(k^2*r0^2*f[z, t]^2))*(D[g[z, t], 
        t] - ((2*g[z, t]/f[z, t])*D[f[z, t], t])) - ((4*g[z, t]*
         Rd)/(t0*k^2*r0^2*f[z, t]^3))*D[f[z, t], t],
  D[f[z, t], z, z] == ( 1/(f[z, t]^3)) - 
    0.5*(wpw)^2*(k^2*
       r0^2/E0)*(g[z, 
        t]/((1 + g[z, t]/2 f[z, t]^2)^(3/2)*f[z, t]^3))}
bcs = {g[0, t] == Exp[-t^2], f[0, t] == 1, 
   Derivative[1, 0][f][0, t] == 0};
ics = {g[z, 0] == 1, f[z, 0] == 1 };

Comment: sol = NDSolveValue[{eqns, bcs, ics}, {g, f}, {z, 0, 5}, {t, -3, 3},
  Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic,
    "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual",
    "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines",
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid",
        "MinPoints" -> 200, "MaxPoints" -> 200}}}]

Comment: @maninderpanesar, please put this in your question not in the comments.

Comment: Please have a look. I have posted new question.